# Google BigQuery: How to remove a column using the bq command line?

Tags: google-bigquery

Table is not that large, I want to remove a column. Tried `bq update project:schema.table schema_one_column_less.json` but got an exception: `BigQuery error in update operation: Provided Schema does not match Table xxx. Field xxxxx is missing in new schema`. What't the right way to remove a column in place (without having to create a new table)?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported by bq update [see here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas).  Google offers the following [workarounds](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#deleting_a_column_from_a_table_schema) which include mechanisms via the CLI, but have drawbacks.

Using the `SELECT * EXCEPT` mechanism you can overwrite the original table which would avoid creating a new table, but might also result in significant query costs.

From the example on the linked page, the command would look something like:

```
bq query \
--destination_table mydataset.mytable \
--replace \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
'SELECT
  * EXCEPT(column_to_delete)
FROM
  mydataset.mytable'
```

Comment: Thanks. What will the SELECT *Except query look like (including overwrite the same table)?   SELECT * EXCEPT column_to_be_deleted FROM my_table. How to add the overwrite part?

Comment: added the example to my answer, but you should read the documentation I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Want to complement the other answer with a pure SQL solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  <your_table> AS
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(<column_to_remove>)
FROM
  <your_table>
```

It is worth mentioning that if there is constrain (say, NOT NULL) in your table, you will have to specify the full column list with the constrain like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  <your_table>(<full_column_list>) AS
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(<column_to_remove>)
FROM
  <your_table>
```